# Non homogenous integral equation with polynomial functions.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals, integral-equations

> Consider  a  non-zero, real-valued   polynomial  function $p(x)=a+bx+cx^2$  of  degree at  most   2. Let $y(x)$ be  any solution of *integral  equation* 
>   $$
>  y (x)=p(x) + \int_{0}^{x}y(t)\sin (x-t)dt .
> $$
>   Then which of the following is true .
>
> - (1) $y (x)$  is  polynomial  function of degree  less  than or equal to 2 .
> - (2) $y (x)$  is  polynomial  function  of  degree  less  than  or equal to 4.
> - (3) if  $b$  is non  zero and $a+2c$  is zero  then $y'(0)=0$.
> - (4) if b is  non zero and $a+2c$  is  zero then $y''(0)=0$.

Using Laplace transformation, i get solution 
$$
y (x)=a +bx +(c/2  + a)x^2 +(a/6)x^3 +(c/12)x^4,
$$
so option( $2$) is correct.  If $b$ is non zero then $y'(0)$ is 
non zero,  but $y''(0) =0$ , so reject  (3). So(2) and 
(4)are correct  am I right?
But I am also confused about (1)  may be there is some polynomial $p (x)$  for which   option (1) is true . But in Question we have to find which is " Necessary" true . 
So option (1) is wrong . Am I right ?

Comment: Please make the effort and use mathjax and the native markup possibilites. Then your question will be easier to read.

Comment: Should there be an $y(t)$ in the integrand of the integral equation?

Comment: Sorry ,  edited Qeustion is suggested to me . But I mistakenly reject it I think . Extremely sorry . I am new on this web site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral equation 
$$
y(x)=p(x)+\int_0^xy(t)\sin(x-t)dt
$$
has derivatives
$$
y'(x)=p'(x)+\int_0^xy(t)\cos(x-t)dt\\
y''(x)=p''(x)+y(x)-\int_0^xy(t)\sin(x-t)dt
$$
It is thus equivalent to the second order ODE
$$
y''(x)=p(x)+p''(x)
$$
with initial conditions $y(0)=p(0)=a$ and $y'(0)=p'(0)=b$. Further, $y''(0)=p''(0)+y(0)=2c+a$.

This should be sufficient to decide all claims, and indeed your decisions are right. (1) would have to be true for all $p$, which is not the case.